# Button text with multiple colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, input

I have an input button element which I would like to include the words "Take me there >" but I want to make the angle bracket a different color from the rest of the text.

Is this possible? I'm happy to use a javascript or jquery fix if necessary.

Comment: why not trying a div with CSS formatting and use as a button by using jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/w3KHd/1/

Use a button with a span inside which sets the font color to whatever color you want. E.g.:

```
<button>Take me there <span style="color: red"> &gt; </span></button>
```

**Update:**

If you want to use the button as a submit button use:

```
<button type="submit">Take me there <span style="color: red"> &gt; </span></button>
```

Comment: Include the code in the answer in addition to providing a link to an example, that way this answer is still useful even after that link no longer works.

Comment: OK, I like this but what if it's a submit button, like `<input type='submit' text='Submit' />`

Comment: `<button type="submit">Take me there <span style="color: red"> &gt; </span></button>` should work, right?

Comment: I think that putting HTML tags into button elements like that is bad for older IE versions as they take whatever is between the <button></button> tags and send that in the form.

Comment: @BillyMoat, actually the problem with IE7 and 6 was [<button> won't work unless you specify type=submit](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/10/30/ie7-requires-typesubmit-for-button-elements)... so in your case, it would work in all major browsers. `<button type='submit'>Take me there <span style="color: red"> &gt; </span></button>` would work perfectly fine for all major browsers.

Comment: Works fine in IE7 and above so that's all good for me, I'm not too worried about catering for anyone using a lesser IE

Comment: @Jason WIlliams - I'm pretty sure that even with type="submit" IE 6/7 still always post the innerHTML of a button element. IE6 posts the innerHTML and all other button parameters as well. I'm happy to be corrected but I'm pretty sure I'm right as I've come across this bug a good few times in the past.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">` you can use "***first-letter***" Pseudo Class as below.

Your style class:

```
<style>
button:first-letter {
color:red;
}</style>
```

Button:

```
<button type="submit">&lt;Take me there ></button>
```